# Translation and etymology of a slang passage

Tags: idioms, british-english, slang, dialects

While reading software-user reviews on Google Play Store, I happened to run across the following (verbatim):

> "I'm game ginger an as wet as, a otters pocket full support to do you will ave to be used andbuy my nickers an then abuse me hardcore Istyley kettle bell"

I gather the young lady was pleased with the software application as she gave it a five-star rating and seemed, well, rather..., enthusiastic. However, I'm still curious as to the literal translation and etymology of the idioms / slang involved. My overall perception was this person is humorously feigning a bawdy Cockney persona. Do you think I'm even close in this assessment?

Comment: Since the only punctuation mark is in the wrong place, it's a bit difficult to tease out! Google informs me that 'wetter than an otter's pocket' is an idiom for 'very wet' which can be used in a sexual sense. "I'm game, Ginger!" sounds Cockney ('game' in the sense of 'eager to participate'). Can't make much of the rest of it.

Comment: Have we really been reduced to this? Sussing out porn-speak from lowlifes? The literal translation? I reckon the OP is an English speaker.

Comment: Are you sure it's not auto-generated spam text? It's common to see random phrases strung together nonsensically in such posts.

Answer (score 6):

Unable to parse this sentence myself, I reached out to slang lexicographer [Jonathan Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathon_Green) of [*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/) and he gave me permission to include his response as an answer.  All formatting included in the answer is my own.

> It's **not especially cockney**, though the terms are **British rather than US or elsewhere**, e.g. Australian.
>
> It's a strange mish-mash and not the most obvious thing to 'translate'. It is, surely, a joke.
>
> Breaking it down she's announcing herself as **a sexually excited ('wet as an otter's pocket')** and **available ('game')** **woman ('ginger', though this could also mean 'prostitute')**, presumably as a result of the software's qualities. **'Buy my nickers' (usually 'knickers') also suggests a working girl.** 'Abuse me hardcore' suggests **sado-masochism** (as also 'you will ave to be used' may do). **'Istyley kettle bell' is probably indicating her name, with 'Istyley' as a version of British black stylee, 'manner'. Thus 'I call myself kettle bell'.** (This could be rhyming slang, but none that I know).

We can conclude that the author of these words was likely British or pretending to be, and was using a large range of slang terms to express a joke about the software's excellence by feigning sexual excitement.  But the sentence is **not particularly cockney** in nature.

Comment: Interesting. How exactly did you "reach out" to Jonathan Green?

Comment: @Clare via email.  I send him citations sometimes so we have a small correspondence.